# Laravel route always not defined although it is declared

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I tried adding a position to my user and setting it on users_positions table.

I created a new query alongside with the auth user create. When re-routing it to the root URL, it always comes back as

InvalidArgumentException
Route [/] not defined.

Controller

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $id = User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'middlename' => $data['middlename'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    DB::table('users_positions')->insert([
        [
            'user_id' => $id->id,
            'position_desc' => $data['position'],
            'primary' => "1",
        ]
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('/')
                    ->with('success', 'Successfully added a user account');
}
```

Route

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('name');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('incident-reports.index');
})->middleware('auth');
```

The query is successful but the route still not defined.
When I try manually going to the root URL http://127.0.0.1:8000. It will work.

My plan is after adding user and the user_position it will come back at root URL and prompting an alert if it is success or error.

Comment: Welcome to SO, `redirect()->route()` wants a route name not a URI, see here in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-named-routes

Answer (score 6):

if you want to redirect with the path, send it as parameter to `redirect()` method

```
return redirect('/');
```

the `route()` method is to redirect to a route by Alias

**route**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('incident-reports.index');
})->middleware('auth')->alias('root');
```

**redirect**

```
return redirect()->route('root');
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line:

```
return redirect()->route('/')
                ->with('success', 'Successfully added a user account');
```

to this

```
return redirect()->to('/')
                ->with('success', 'Successfully added a user account');
```

`route()` expects a route name as argument. `'/'` is a url